# Proof Verification for Analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

Problem is from a course in Real Analysis from the chapter on differentiation.

Problem is as follows:

Let $f:[0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f(0)=0$

Suppose $|f'(x)|\leq|f(x)|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$

Show that for all $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=0$.

My proof is as follows:

Suppose $\exists a\in[0,1]$ such that $f(a)>0$. Since [0,1] is compact, by the Extreme Value Theorem, we know there exists some $b\in[0,1]$ such that $|f(b)| \geq |f(x)|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Now consider the interval $[0,b]$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we know $\exists c\in(0,b)$ such that $|f'(c)| = |\frac{f(b)}{b}|\geq|f(b)|\geq|f(c)|$ since $b<=1$. Thus we have a contradiction. We can repeat a similar proof if $\exists a\in[0,1]$ such that $f(a)<0$. Thus for all $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=0$.

Can I check, if there are any errors in my proof, or did I miss out on anything?

Comment: $|f'(c)| \ge |f(c)|$ is not a contradiction...

Comment: I know that you are asking for a proof verification, but I'll mention that this problem has been solved many times on this site, as you can find out [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cf%27(x)%7C%5Cleq%7Cf(x)%7C%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Martin R

 Thanks, for recommending the link.


Just to clarify, the detail missed is that I can choose $b = sup \{ y | f(y) \geq f(x) 
  \forall x \in[0,1]\} $
if b<1, then the inequality is strict, and there is a contradiction right. But if b = 1, then since $c\in(0,1)$ then then $|f(b)| > |f(c)|$ then there is also a contradiction then alls good right?